# Issue in WFS transaction using geoserver and openlayers

Tags: geoserver, wfs, insert

I am working on web application for providing editing functionality. I have written code for capturing new feature through draw interaction and generating WFS transaction payload as given below.

Code is executing successfully without giving error. Record is inserted in PostGIS database but geometry is not updated.

```js
function newSaveEdits(editTaskName) {
  var format = new ol.format.WFS({featureNS:"Test",featureType:'building',schemaLocation:"http://www.opengis.net/wfs" + 
                    "http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd" + 
                    "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/grp/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=Test:building"});
  clones = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < modifiedFeatureList.length; i++) {
    var feature = modifiedFeatureList[i];
    var featureProperties = feature.getProperties();

    delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
    var clone = feature.clone();
    // clone.setId(feature.getId());

    // clone.setGeometryName('geom');
    clone.set('geometry', feature.getGeometry());
    clones.push(clone)
    // if (editTaskName == 'insert') { transactWFS('insert', clone); }
  }
  var node = format.writeTransaction(clones, null, null, {
    gmlOptions: { srsName: "EPSG:3857" },
    featureNS: "Test",
    featureType: "Test:building"
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wfs",
    data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node),
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    success: function (data) {
      // var result = format.readTransactionResponse(data);
      // feature.setId(result.insertIds[0]);
    },
    error: function (e) {
      var errorMsg = e ? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
      bootbox.alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer.<br><br>'
        + errorMsg);
    },
    context: this
  });


}
```

XML transaction

```xml
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS"
version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><Insert><Test:shpbuilding
xmlns:Test="Test"><Test:geometry><Polygon
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
srsName="EPSG:3857"><exterior><LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857"><posList
srsDimension="2">8772698.667721646 3400281.53423941 8772700.757796638
3400291.686032229 8772715.239030512 3400285.4158072523 8772698.667721646 3400281.53423941</posList></LinearRing></exterior></Polygon></Test:geometry></Test:shpbuilding></Insert></Transaction>
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please just fix the original question and stop posting new ones.

Comment: Please do not delete and re-ask the same question. The community needs to review your original to decide whether it is ready to be re-opened.